# Website 403 error after opening zip in public_html in cPanel file manager

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cpanel, whm

I messed up and opened up a zip file in my website's public_html directory. I deleted all of the files but my website is now throwing a 403 forbidden error. The website is connected to a wordpress. cPanel's rollback feature was disabled when this happened. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is to log in using FileZilla or some other FTP programs and look for missing wordpress files! You might have deleted an important component that wordpress needs to run by accident. Under the Public_html you should see a list of the following files:

[image: wordpress hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the file I unzipped contained a file with the same as an existing file in the directory. If this happens to you, it is likely there is a backup of the overwritten file somewhere. Look for index.html first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).